# Special characters in a Windows filename

Tags: windows, filesystems

Why can we not use any special characters (?, <..) in a Windows filename?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename

Comment: Because they have special meanings like input/output redirection, drive letter delimiter, 32k Unicode name support etc

Comment: similar [What characters are forbidden in Windows and Linux directory names?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1976007/what-characters-are-forbidden-in-windows-and-linux-directory-names)

Comment: More specifically, *"[Reserved characters and words, In Windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filename#In_Windows)"*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because they have special meanings in the filesystem:

C:*.? - get all files with single letter extensions from the C drive

: \ * ? - all have special meanings

Answer (score 5):

**Fundamental rules** for [Universal Naming Convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_%28computing%29#Uniform_Naming_Convention) (UNC), which enable applications to create and process valid names for files and directories, regardless of the file system:

**The following reserved characters:**

> - < (less than)
> - > (greater than)
> - : (colon)
> - " (double quote)
> - / (forward slash)
> - \ (backslash)
> - | (vertical bar or pipe)
> - ? (question mark)
> - * (asterisk)

Use any character in the current [code page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page) for a name, including Unicode characters and characters in the extended character set (128–255).

Comment: This lists the characters (which is useful), but it doesn't answer the question (*** *** *** ***why*** *** *** ***). Whether that is a useful question is another matter.

Answer (score 0):

Since some characters are *reserved* characters in some operating systems, say `?` is used as a wildcard, and `/` as a path name component separator.

Comment: But this is specifically about Windows.

Comment: Forward slash for Windows could need an explanation.

Comment: That they are reserved characters doesn't answer the question (*** *** *** ***why*** *** *** ***). Whether that is a useful question is another matter.